# limited sum in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

suppose I have this table

```
var
10
3
4
60
70
```

and I want to take the sum of var. Is there a way to limit the amount of vars added to the total sum on each row

so usually you do `SELECT SUM(var)` but say I want to limit each row to only contribute a maximum of 5 points to the sum. Hence I'd like the final sum to be (5+3+4+5+5) = 22 (since 10, 60, and 70 exceed 5) rather than the usual result of 147 for SUM(var)

is there a way to specify the mysql query to do such thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(LEAST(5, var)) as modified_total;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least

Comment: I think OP wants SUM(LEAST(var,5)) instead?

Comment: @themel, I fixed it a second ago...  I got confused.  Hit refresh.